# Make output of a function available to other function

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to make some user information available to two different functions in my view.py. But, I want to hit database only once, not twice. 
Is there a way I can do this?

Here is the function that outputs some user info (**userlocs**):

```
def get_user_info(profile_ins):
    fav_loc = list()
    lat = list()
    lon = list()
    for loc in UserLoc.objects.filter(profile=profile_ins):
        fav_loc.append(loc.name)
        lat.append(loc.location.geo_code_lat)
        lon.append(loc.location.geo_code_lon)
    userlocs = list(zip(fav_loc, lat, lon))
    return userlocs
```

This is the view function when user looks at his profile. This is where I first call get_user_info:

```
def profile(request):
    profile_instance = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    userlocs = get_user_info(profile_instance)
    context = {'locations': userlocs}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Now, I want the **userloc** list to be available to the following function too. This function is supposed to compare user input to the existing **userloc** info. I know I can again call get_user_info function, but I think this is redundant, as I already called it once.

```
def add_location_exe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ln = UserLocForm(request.POST or None)
        if ln.is_valid():
            name = ln.cleaned_data.get("name")
            ## is name in userloc list ##
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Save the result of the function call in a program wide variable. That way, you'll be able to use the result throughout the program.

Comment: But what if the database changes between the calls to these separate views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about two view functions that are supposed to access the same global variable. This is not a good idea for more than one reason:

1. The content of `userloc` depends on the state of the database. Since you only call one view per request, the data might have changed.
2. You have no guarantee that the two requests are even handled by the same Python process. Hence, there is no such thing as a global variable that can be set and persisted across requests.

For both those reasons, real global variables (the ones that do not change; not database records!) should be kept in the settings. If you want to limit database accesses in a complex application during one request-response cycle, you can use the [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) decorator:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, profile_ins):
        self.profile_ins = profile_ins

    @cached_property
    def get_user_info(self):
        return ...

# views.py
# ...
    foo = Foo()
```

This will cache the value of `foo.get_user_info` for the entire cycle.

Comment: You are right. Didn't think of possibility of changes in the db between two requests. Thanks for your response.